# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in LINQ

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Linq query where I am trying to write subquery to set the value of item, I am encountering with error saying
{ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
}, Please let me know the right syntax to make it work

```
var lst = (
    from cr in dbContext.Company
    orderby cr.COMPANY_KEY
    select new CompanyDto()
    {
        CompanyKey = cr.CompanyKey,
        CompanyCode = (from rc in dbContext.COMPANY_PORTFOLIOS where rc.PORTFOLIO == cr.P_PORTFOLIO  select rc.COMPANY_CODE).FirstOrDefault()
    }
);
var d = st.Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Even the below piece of code is not working

```
var lst = (
    from cr in dbContext.Company
    orderby cr.COMPANY_KEY
    select new CompanyDto()
    {
        CompanyKey = cr.CompanyKey,
        CompanyCode = (from rc in dbContext.COMPANY_PORTFOLIOS where rc.PORTFOLIO == cr.P_PORTFOLIO  select rc.COMPANY_CODE).Single()
    }
);
var d = st.Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: Check inner exception of the error, sometimes I encountered "Oracle [version] does not support XXXX" there while working with EF.

Comment: inner exception says {"ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"}

Comment: Seems that `FirstOrDefault()` or `Single()` involving tuples, there's a chance that `DISTINCT` or `LIMIT` in generated query missing some value & causing break-of-statement due to assignment for closing parenthesis after missing value which should have present. I want to know the generated query result for both `FirstOrDefault` & `Single` usage.

Comment: single and singleOrDefaullt() not support to Multiple values .its only accept single value  so check values

Comment: Deffefenedly comes Company code you have used join clause. this performance better for your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use a Join to achieve what you are looking to do:

```
var lst = (
    from cr in dbContext.Company
    orderby cr.COMPANY_KEY
    join rc in dbContext.COMPANY_PORTFOLIOS on cr.PORTFOLIO equals rc.P_PORTFOLIO into myJoin
    from rc in myJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new CompanyDto()
    {
       CompanyKey = cr.CompanyKey,
       CompanyCode = rc.COMPANY_CODE
    }
);
var d = lst.Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

If the above still gives Oracle errors, put a breakpoint at the last line and get the SQL the linq generates. You can then paste this into something like Oracle SQL Developer and run the query, which may give you a more informative error message and allow you to track down the issue.

Comment: am getting this error The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: @mahesh Just use the OrderBy method prior to the Skip method call e.g. `lst.OrderBy(l => l.CompanyKey).Skip(pageIndex)`. You can probably remove the earlier orderby call within the query.